# Which technique determines if var x1 leads var y? Assuming var x1 may need to be transformed

Tags: statistics, prediction

Suppose I want to predict future changes in variable y (stock price over time). I notice that variable x1, inverted and delayed three months, tends to lead y. Which technique can I use to find other predictive relationships like this? Suppose I have variables x2 through x100 that I want to analyze to see if they also lead y in some way.

What are the non-machine learning (ie traditional statistical) options? Do the machine learning ones work better?

Context: want to predict future changes in S&P 500 price based on other assets like gold, oil, currencies, etc.

Comment: Have you looked into regression models?

Comment: Somewhat, but I'm unsure how to pick the best type. What if, given another transformation of my predictor variable X1, a completely different type of regression would work best?